# Border not showing up in table, HTML, CSS, PHP

Tags: html, css

The border isn't showing up in the table for some reason when I'm using css to style it. However, if I style in directly inside the table tag, it works. Please take a look at my code:

**test.php**

```
<head>
<style>

table {
border: 1px solid black;
}

</style>
</head>

<?php

echo "<body>";
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";

echo "<td> hello1 </td>";
echo "<td> hello2 </td>";
echo "<td> hello3 </td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
echo "</body>";

?>
```

Comment: Working [here](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/jr4260hx/)

Comment: You mean [this](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/jr4260hx/1/)?

Comment: Something like that, yes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this code...

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head><title>Demo</title></head>
  <body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Test1</td>
        <td>Test2</td>
        <td>Test3</td>
        <td>Test4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want borders around the td elements as well. If so I would recommend this:

```
table {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

The border-collapse removes any spaces between the borders.

Comment: Not sure why they even have spaces between the borders in the first place. I'm sure most people agrees that no spaces looks so much better.

Comment: I guess its the same as all elements (divs, tables etc). All of them have some default padding/margins.